# Gatsby eslint-loader is logging all errors to the terminal window - why?

Tags: terminal, eslint, gatsby

Everytime I run `gatsby develop`, I get a massive log of errors in my terminal window. I have searched and tried in vain to stop this from happening, any ideas?

E.g.

```
✖ 654 problems (654 errors, 0 warnings)
  400 errors, 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable eslint in gatsby by adding an empty `.eslintrc` file at the root of your project.

```
root
  |--src
  |--gatsby-config.js
  `--.eslintrc
```

eslint is helpful for avoiding silly mistakes though! If you'd like to use eslint, but use your own rules, checkout [eslint website](https://eslint.org/).

Alternatively, you can [setup your code editor / ide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/integrations) so that eslint display error as you code.